# Why are these list items on the same line when using map() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add names to a list in React using map(), but the names are coming out on the same line on the list. If I change it to hard code some list elements, they come out on different lines like I want. I want to display the list using map(). I checked documentation and tried to find similar questions and still can't figure out what's wrong.

An edit: I also realize that I have a problem with id where the same item name could have different ids, but I know how to fix that and am wondering about the other question for now.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: [],
      data: '',
      url: '',
      breed: '',
      list: []
    }
  }

  dogBreed = () => {
    console.log('Breed name');
    let currentURL = this.state.data.message.slice();
    let endOfURL = currentURL.slice(30);
    let middleOfURL = endOfURL.split("/")[0];
    if (middleOfURL.includes('-')) {
      let name = middleOfURL.split("-");
      middleOfURL = name[1] + " " + name[0];
    }
    console.log(middleOfURL);
    this.setState({breed: middleOfURL});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json =>
        this.setState({data: json}, () => 
          this.dogBreed()
        )
      );
  }

  changeDoggo = () => {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => 
        this.setState({data: json}, () => 
         this.dogBreed()
        )
      )
  }

  addDoggo = () => {
    const updatedList = [...this.state.list];
    this.setState({list: [updatedList.concat(this.state.breed)]});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>It's a {this.state.breed}!</h1>
        <div className="picture">
          <img src={this.state.data.message} alt="dog" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.changeDoggo}>Change Doggo</button>
      </div>
      <div className="listDiv">
        <h1>List of doggos I want...</h1>
        <button onClick={this.addDoggo}>Add Current Doggo</button>
        <ul>
        {this.state.list.map((item, id) => (
          <li key={id}>{item}</li>
        ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'd suggest check the (resulting) CSS using e.g. Chrome's DevTools.

Comment: Please include all relevant code (including rendered HTML and CSS). You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to produce something we can view.

Comment: @KevinSchoofs That worked. In the addDoggo method, I was putting the array inside of another array. The developer tools showed me that. Thank you for teaching me that.